# How to get the mysql table columns data type?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the column data type of a mysql table.

Thought I could use `MYSQLFIELD` structure but it was enumerated field types.

Then I tried with `mysql_real_query()`

The error which i am getting is `query was empty`

How do I get the column data type?

Answer (score 153):

You can use the [information_schema columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col_name';
```

Comment: Don't forget: AND INDEX_SCHEMA = 'database_name'

Comment: I personally tried this and would agree this answer does do what the OP intended to. On a side note a bit weird on how "table_name" is small caps even in the manual, should it not be UPPER? (Not that it makes a difference)

Comment: Also note if the data type has a set length, eg. VARCHAR(50) one can use `SELECT COLUMN_TYPE` to get that extra information.

Comment: if INDEX_SCHEMA doesn't work then try TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'

Comment: This query is useless when you want to know the type for all columns (removing `AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col_name'`) unless you display the column name : `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM etc.`.

Comment: Maybe it should be noted that this query doesn't give all information about the data type in a broader view, e.g. one could have a 4-byte integer type for some column, and regardless of whether it is signed or unsigned, the given query would always give `int`

Comment: This didn't work for me because I removed the single quote. Check your single quote if it didn't work.

Comment: @chutsu In my experience, MySQL doesn't actually care about casing for e.g. column names or reserved words.

Answer (score 111):

The query below returns a list of information about each field, including the MySQL field type. Here is an example:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM tablename
/* returns "Field", "Type", "Null", "Key", "Default", "Extras" */
```

See [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html).

Comment: An alternative is EXPLAIN tablename;

Comment: This answer requires further handling to get the type... The answer user83591 gave is much better

Comment: Add `WHERE FIELD = '<your column name>'` if you want a single column info.

Answer (score 64):

Most answers are duplicates, it might be useful to group them.  Basically two simple options have been proposed.

### First option

The first option has 4 different aliases, some of which are quite short :

```
EXPLAIN db_name.table_name;
DESCRIBE db_name.table_name;
SHOW FIELDS FROM db_name.table_name;
SHOW COLUMNS FROM db_name.table_name;
```

NB: In each case, you can also write `FROM` two times instead of `db_name.table_name`, example:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM table_name FROM db_name
```

This gives something like :

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name             | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| description      | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| meta_title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

### Second option

The second option is a bit longer :

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
AND
  TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

It is also less talkative :

```
+------------------+-----------+
| column_name      | DATA_TYPE |
+------------------+-----------+
| product_id       | int       |
| name             | varchar   |
| description      | text      |
| meta_title       | varchar   |
+------------------+-----------+
```

It has the advantage of allowing selection per column, though, using `AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'` (or `like`).

Comment: This second option was exactly what I needed. Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 29):

To get data types of all columns:

```
describe table_name
```

or just a single column:

```
describe table_name column_name
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do this.  You just saved me a bunch of tramping through the information schema.

Answer (score 20):

Please use the below mysql query.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = '<DATABASE NAME>' 
AND table_name = '<TABLE NAME>' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = '<COLOMN NAME>'
```

[image: MySql Query Result]

Comment: But this will give only the maximum length. Isn't it better to use `SELECT DATA_TYPE`, as proposed by other answers?

Comment: Yes, You are right. I just forgot to add it. I am now corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

First select the Database using `use testDB;` then execute

```
desc `testDB`.`images`;
-- or
SHOW FIELDS FROM images;
```

**Output:**

[image: Get Table Columns with DataTypes]

Answer (score 5):

Refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable FROM mydb;
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable;
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 2):

Query to find out all the datatype of columns being used in any database

```
SELECT distinct DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE table_schema = '<db_name>' AND column_name like '%';
```

Comment: Isn't `AND column_name like '%'` superfluous ?

Answer (score 1):

SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable

Self contained complete examples are often useful.

```
<?php
  // The server where your database is hosted                 localhost
  // The name of your database                                mydatabase
  // The user name of the database user                       databaseuser
  // The password of the database user                        thesecretpassword
  // Most web pages are in utf-8 so should be the database    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
  try
  {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase", "databaseuser", "thesecretpassword", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));  
  }
    catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }

  $sql   = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable";
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute();

  $err = $query->errorInfo();
  $bug = $err[2];

  if ($bug != "") { echo "<p>$bug</p>"; }

  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($row, true) . "</pre>";
  }

  /* OUTPUT SAMPLE  
  Array
  (
      [Field] => page_id
      [Type] => char(40)
      [Null] => NO
      [Key] => 
      [Default] => 
      [Extra] => 
  )

  Array
  (  
      [Field] => last_name
      [Type] => char(50)
      More ...
  */
?>
```

Comment: The OP did not tag this question with the `php` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet rs = Sstatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Table Name");

ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
System.out.println("resultSet MetaData column Count=" + numberOfColumns);

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
 System.out.println("column number " + i);

  System.out.println(rsMetaData.getColumnTypeName(i));
}
```

Comment: The OP did not tag this question with the `java` tag.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT  * FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SCHEMA_NAME' AND COLUMN_KEY='PRI';
  WHERE COLUMN_KEY='PRI';

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
TABLE_CATALOG,
TABLE_SCHEMA,
TABLE_NAME, 
COLUMN_NAME, 
DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).