# How to know the column data type?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm using Mysql2 to deal with an external database, I'm not using ActiveRecord.

```
database = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => ....)
@table = database.query("select * from ....")
```

I don't know the column names, but it provide me a hash of rows each with the column names.

But this is still not enough, I want to know the column data type, is it a `varchar`, `int`, `datetime` and specially if it's a `blob`.

Is there a way I can know the data type of the table's columns??

Comment: Execute the query `DESCRIBE tablename`.  Rails  probably has some wrapper method around that but that's how to get MySQL to tell you about a table.

Comment: hmmm, it will work, I was just looking for a 'ruby side' solution and didn't think about 'mysql side', thumbs up
you can answer it to vote on it

Comment: Maybe this previous mysql question could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215368/how-to-get-the-mysql-table-columns-data-type

Comment: thanks Svennises, it's similar to Michael's solution

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know the type as seen by Rails (meaning, through `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters`) you can use the method `column` on your model class

Ex for a User model: `User.columns`. Try it in your console.

To get the type of all columns, you can do `User.columns.map{|col| col.type}`

Comment: it's not a model, it's just a connection to a separate DB
it's not the DB where the rails model come from