# How select column names ,column data type, key column of a table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

How select column names ,column data type, key column of a table in mysql by passing the table name.
I am using mysql 5.5

Answer (score 4):

Pick the info you need from

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

Comment: +1 @java baba: Alternately, if your goal is just to see the information but you don't literally need a `select`, you can do `describe your_table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Get structure of table

```
DESCRIBE table;

SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables  where table_name = 'table';
```

Get a list of the tables in your database.

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

Whole database structure

```
mysqldump database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select database,
2. execute command using `desc` or `SHOW FIELDS FROM`.

**Code:**

```
`use testDB;`

``desc `testDB`.`images`;``

-- or

`SHOW FIELDS FROM images;`
```

See my previous answer [How to show mysql table columns data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274290/1624035), it solves your problem.

The results are shown in attached image file.