# How to determine datatype in database of value if value could have several datatypes

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling, entity-attribute-value

I'm currently designing a database for a project. Let's imagine having an object, which is collecting data. It has an object-type and every collected data-value has an object, which is collecting data-values.

```
objectType((PK)id, name);
object((PK)id, name, (FK)objectType);
objectValue((PK)id, value, timestamp, (FK)object);
```

objectValue.value could be a string, int, boolean etc. In the database it is saved as a string to include all types. How should I specify the datatype for this property? Is it a good thing to save the datatype of the value in the objectType table as a string? Is it good practice considering the code (ORM) for my program? How should I handle this? What's a common way to solve this issue?

Comment: you wozld chekc what kind of tyo the column has. like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215368/how-to-get-the-mysql-table-columns-data-type

Comment: My issue is not to get the datatype of the column. My issue is to save the exact datatype of objectValue.value because depending on the objectType it could have different datatypes

Comment: when you create the table in your case ObjectValue, you have to tell mysql what Datatype value exactly has. What mysql interprets from the content follow rules. What you make of the content is anothermatter, you could convert it into bit for example. If you alter the column now and then, my first comment is valid

Comment: Sounds like you are going down the slippery slope into the EAV abyss.

Comment: Jsut add a column beside value saying what its type is. But if those types are DBMS types then you are better to have specialized columns--together in a table or in separate tables--each with that type containing rows each with an object & its value of that type. Use the functionality of the DBMS to do typechecking for you when application types are its types.

Comment: EAV is usually considered an anti pattern when it comes to database structure. You should consider either using a solid, hardcoded schema or types like xml / json instead.