# Default value depending on column type mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

Is there some way to set `DEFAULT` value to column in MySQL depending on its type (like this happen with variables of primitive types in Java)?

For example, 0 for numeric types, empty string for `VARCHAR`, `FALSE` for boolean etc.

Or how to get default value of `mysql` type in my Java program and set it manually without a thousand of `if` statements? (I use JDBC to work with DB).

Comment: in mysql 8 you can use functions and there is that https://stackoverflow.com/a/1216253/5193536  but i don't think that it is possible, but you can try

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set default value for columns in CREATE/ALTER TABLE statements:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    ID bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    Age int DEFAULT 21,
    Location varchar(255) DEFAULT 'London',
    Joining_Date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

Or, if you use JPA entities mapped to the table, you can set `columnDefinition` parameter:

```
@Column(name = "Location" columnDefinition="DEFAULT 'London'")
private String location;
```

As for your question about retrieval of default settings via JDBC - it is also possible via method `getColumns` of `DatabaseMetadata` class where you can [read column `COLUMN_DEF`](http://javanotes2all.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-do-i-use-databasemetadata-to-get.html).