# How to get the data type of columns fetched across all PDO drivers?

Tags: php, pdo

I am using the following (`array_keys`) to get column names from SQL statements:

```
$this_sql="select * from orders";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($this_sql);
$stmt->execute();
$resultz = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach(array_keys($resultz) as $column_names)
{
    echo $column_names;
}
```

Is there a similar way to get the datatypes of the columns? For instance: int, float, varchar, etc.?

I read about `getColumnMeta` but I also understand that does not work for all drivers.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: @Dharman - I was hoping for a solution that worked with multiple drivers. Right now I am using both pdo_mysql.so and pdo_odbc.dll.  ...[edit]...also php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.

Comment: Not exactly similar, most probably you should read data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215368/how-to-get-the-mysql-table-columns-data-type/31830486

Comment: @biesior - thank you, I am familiar with information_schema. I was recently told that the datatypes are in the result set - I was not certain if this was true.  I was intrigued but also was not finding a way after hours of searching.

Comment: hm... dunno, maybe you mean `$stmt->getColumnMeta(0)` ?